# How can I expand the inner parentheses of trigonometric functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
Sqrt[3] Sin[π/4 x - π/3] /. x -> 2 - x // FullSimplify
```

Using the above code, I obtain:

```
Sqrt[3] Cos[1/12 π (4 + 3 x)]
```

The desired result is:

```
Sqrt[3] Cos[π/3 + (π x)/4]
```

I tried this method but it didn't work. How can I get the desired result?

```
Expand /@ Sqrt[3] Sin[π/4 x - π/3] /. x -> 2 - x // FullSimplify
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ExpandAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html). However, it will also turn `Cos` into `Sin`.

```
ExpandAll[Sqrt[3] Sin[π/4 x - π/3] /. x -> 2 - x]
(* Sqrt[3] Sin[π/6 - (π x)/4] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep `Cos` instead of turning into `Sin`:

```
Sqrt[3] Cos[1/12 \[Pi] (4 + 3 x)] /. Cos -> Inactive[Cos]@*Expand
```

Comment: After this conversion, the next step of operation cannot be performed